# How atob doesn't convert from Buffer with base64?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have data that I encrypt using [lz-string](https://github.com/pieroxy/lz-string) package.

I also convert the result to base64 and using `atob()` function to convert from base64.

The problem is [atob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/atob) doesn't work as expected but `Buffer.from(b64, 'base64').toString();` does.

Why? how do I fix that? I need to use `atob` in the client side (the Buffer is not exist in the browser).

[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-gvaknf)

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work as expected" ?

Comment: atob should convert back from base64.. but as you run my example it not doing that. at least not with the correct chars.

Comment: `atob` does convert from base64, I've used it often enough, but it does not interpret the input as UTF-8, unlike `Buffer.toString()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `decodeURIComponent` and `escape` to convert to UTF-8.

```
const non64 = decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob( b64 )));
```

Comment: it is working but escape method is deprecated, when I test it without escape I get URI malformed error

Answer (score 0):

The more effective (see below) option would be, if your LZ library supports it, to *not* interpret the base64-encoded buffer as a string and pass it to the library as a Uint8Array directly. You can do that with

```
const buffer = Uint8Array.from(atob(b64), c => c.charCodeAt(0))
```

And then if you really need a string, you can use a TextDecoder, which is a bit less hacky than Shlomi's admittedly very nice solution:

```
const text = new TextDecoder().decode(buffer)
```

There are a couple reasons why using a TypedArray is more effective and an implementation of LZ should really work on them rather than strings (and probably use WebAssembly). Obviously you skip the UTF-8 decoding, but the more significant reason is because in JavaScript, strings are represented in memory as UTF-16, so each character takes at least 2 bytes (exactly 2 bytes in the case of a binary string) whereas the Uint8Array — as the name suggests — only uses one byte per item.